# Three column graph

Tags: r, plot, igraph

The result of some process is a list of paths from A to C through B, e.g.:

```
which.effect(A1,A2,10,1,1)
[[1]]
[1] 10  2  1

[[2]]
[1] 10 28  1

[[3]]
[1] 10  6  9

[[4]]
[1] 10 24  9

[[5]]
[1] 10 28  9
```

What I would like to have is a graph with three parallel columns, the first for the origin, the  second for the intermediate point, and the third for the destination. In this example, the first column would have only the node `10`, the second `2, 6, 24, 28` and the third `1, 9`. Then, directed edges (arrows) will go from nodes in the first column to nodes in the second column, and from nodes in the second column to nodes in the third one.

Is this even possible with `igraph`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I mistakenly deleted @gabor-csardi answer. Is there a way to recover it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you want but maybe gets you some of the way there.

The idea is to first form an edge list from your data, to then create an adjacency matrix and then plot.

```
library(igraph)
library(Rgraphviz)

# your data
lst <- list(c(10,2,1), c(10,28,1), c(10,6,9), c(10,24,9), c(10,28,9))

# create edge list (from in first column / to in the second)
d <- do.call(rbind, lst)
edges <- rbind(d[,1:2], d[,2:3])

# get adjacency matrix
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed=TRUE)
adj <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(g)) 

# convert to a graph object and plot
g2 <- new("graphAM", adjMat=adj, edgemode="directed")
plot(g2, attrs = list(graph = list(rankdir="LR"), 
                             node = list(fillcolor = "lightblue")))
```

`rankdir="LR"` plots the graph from left to right

[image]

Above plot uses `dot` to give the strict structure.

**EDIT**

Use `layout = layout.reingold.tilford` to get a tree structure using `igraph`

```
E(g)$curved <- 0
plot.igraph(g, vertex.size=30, layout=layout.reingold.tilford)
```