# 3 column CSV, to adjacency matrix, to networkgraph, to Arcplot

Tags: r, graph, social-networking

I'm attempting to convert a CSV with 3 columns to an arcplot. The columns - `A`, `B`, `C` always go in the order `A` -> `B` -> `C`. However, I did not see a way to realize this as an arcplot as it seemed most approaches utilized a two column edge plot. Consequently, I've been following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441094/three-column-graph) to convert to an adjacency matrix.

I'll recreate the problem below - but not generating faux data, as one concern is that the CSV might not be read in correctly.

Basically, the CSV contains rows, where each column is separated by a `,` but may contain multiple values separated by `;` such as:

> ```
> ENV;MO,echoic;tact,social 
> ENV;MO,mand,physical
> OVB,intraverbal,social
> ENV;OVB,tact,social
> OVB,intraverbal;tact,social
> OVB;ENV;MO,intraverbal;mand,social
> OVB;ENV;MO,intraverbal;mand,physical;social
> ENV;MO,mand,social;physical
> ```

I am attempting the following in order to accomplish some network graphing before moving to arcplots:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
lst <- read.csv("abc.csv", header=FALSE)

#this is pretty much straight from the link above
d <- do.call(rbind, lst)
edges <- rbind(d[ ,1:2], d[ ,2:3])
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed=TRUE)
adj <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(g)) 
g2 <- new("graphAM", adjMat=adj, edgemode="directed")
plot(g2, attrs = list(graph = list(rankdir="LR"), node = list(fillcolor = "lightblue")))
```

The result is pretty much not at all what I was hoping for. Rather than elements from column `A` pointing to `B` pointing to `C`. Rather it's just one element from A pointing to itself; one from `B` pointing to another pointing to another e.g., `intraverbal` -> `mand` -> `intraverbal`; `tact`, and one from `C` pointing to itself and another value from `C`.

Addendum: Given the `A` -> `B` -> `C` format, a line such as

> OVB;ENV;MO,intraverbal;mand,social

denotes

> A(OVB&ENV&MO) -> B(intraverbal&mand) -> C(social)

Though it may exceed the scope of the question, the end goal would be arc-graphs similar to those depicted here [PDF guide to arcplots in R](http://gastonsanchez.com/software/arcdiagram_introduction.pdf)

Comment: Not sure aboutn the multiple values separated by ";"... for example the first row should become: `ENV->echoic->social + ENV->tact->social + MO->echoic->social + MO->tact->social` is it right ?

Comment: It should be ENV/MO -> echoic/tact -> social 
The A column has some combination of ENV, MO, or OVB; The B column some combination of tact, mand, echoic, or intraverbal; the C column social, physical, or social/physical or physical/social. FWIW replacing ';' with '-' gives the same results

Comment: FWIW - I just discovered a problem with newlines! I used dos2unix and have added quotes around each column value. I'll see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code (it doesn't even need igraph actually...):

```
# of course you need to install arcdiagram first
# as described in the pdf
library(arcdiagram) 

DF <- read.table(text=
"ENV;MO,echoic;tact,social 
ENV;MO,mand,physical
OVB,intraverbal,social
ENV;OVB,tact,social
OVB,intraverbal;tact,social
OVB;ENV;MO,intraverbal;mand,social
OVB;ENV;MO,intraverbal;mand,physical;social
ENV;MO,mand,social;physical",sep=',')

# replace ";" with "&\n"
DF[] <- lapply(DF,function(x)gsub(';',' &\n',x))

# create adjacency matrix
m <- rbind(as.matrix(DF[,1:2]),as.matrix(DF[,2:3]))

# plot...
arcplot(m ,col.arcs='DodgerBlue',lwd.arcs=2,col.labels='black',las=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if that's what you want. However you can try:

```
require(igraph)
df[]<-lapply(df,strsplit,";")
el<-as.matrix(do.call(rbind,apply(df,1,expand.grid)))
g<-graph_from_edgelist(rbind(el[,-3],el[,-1]))
plot(g)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df<-structure(list(V1 = c("ENV;MO", "ENV;MO", "OVB", "ENV;OVB", "OVB", 
"OVB;ENV;MO", "OVB;ENV;MO", "ENV;MO"), V2 = c("echoic;tact", 
"mand", "intraverbal", "tact", "intraverbal;tact", "intraverbal;mand", 
"intraverbal;mand", "mand"), V3 = c("social", "physical", "social", 
"social", "social", "social", "physical;social", "social;physical"
)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I didn't necessarily want to split the ';' joined values - but it looks great. I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Don't know if you want the multiple values to be single nodes of the graph. If that's the case, starting from the `df` of my answer, maybe `graph_from_edgelist(rbind(as.matrix(df)[,-3],as.matrix(df[,-1])))` suffices.

Comment: The resulting image is a bit dense - http://imgur.com/p4KnVjD but I'll look at the igraph options and try to tweak it

Comment: Hey Nicola this was a great answer. I'll post a bounty to you when it comes available - thank you.